# Grails - Servlet 3.0 Asynchronous Request Processing

Tags: grails, asynchronous, controller, httprequest, servlet-3.0

I discovered today Servlet 3.0 asynchronous facility. I have read about it and think I understood the concept.

I was wondering: would that make any difference on "standard" controller's actions, or should it be saved for the use of web services, or extensive computational processes ?

In other words, is it a bad idea to use it on all one's controller's actions, without considering the computational time of the actions method beforehand? 
If it is, could you explained to me why ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this would be a bad idea.

On a controller action, you get a request and you want to serve a response as soon as possible. You can use the asynchronous only for thing that can be delayed.

If a user is requesting a page on your website, you can't respond with empty page, then do a push back to update his page. I would use this feature only for AJAX requests and even not for all of them. You have to decide what makes sense to run be run asynchronously and what not.

Comment: Can most of the popular Java web containers handle more than one request at a time? That is, if a request blocks, will that put all future requests into a queue until the original request has finished? For me, this would be the main reason to use ayncs: To free up the server.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the Grails documentation for [Asynchronous Request Handling](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/async.html#asyncRequests)

> In general for controller actions that execute quickly there is little benefit in handling requests asynchronously. However, for long running controller actions it is extremely beneficial.
>
> The reason being that with an asynchronous / non-blocking response, the one thread == one request == one response relationship is broken. The container can keep a client response open and active, and at the same time return the thread back to the container to deal with another request, improving scalability.

Hopefully this should be clear enough, but please ask if something is not clear.